# CarrierWave: allowing one-by-one file uploads as well as a bulk zip upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm using CarrierWave to upload and manage resources on my ActiveRecord models. I've defined my own Uploader and mounted it to a bunch of properties on one of my models as shown below:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  mount_uploader :masthead, ThemeResourceUploader
  mount_uploader :background, ThemeResourceUploader
  mount_uploader :footer, ThemeResourceUploader
  ...
end
```

This works as expected when creating a new Theme from the params in my Rails controller, but in addition to allowing the user to upload one image at a time I also want to allow them to upload an zip file containing all these images and then use this zip to construct the Theme.

To try and accomplish this I created a new Uploader for the zip file and a controller method which uses Rubyzip to extract the uploaded zip in memory and then tries to assign the resultant stream to my ActiveRecord model's properties.

```
def import
  require 'zip'

  @theme = Theme.new

  zip_upload = params.require(:theme).require(:zip)
  uploader = ThemeImportUploader.new
  uploader.cache!(zip_upload)

  Zip::File.open(uploader.file.path) do |zip_file|
    @theme.masthead = zip_file.get_input_stream('masthead.png')
    @theme.background = zip_file.get_input_stream('background.png')
    @theme.footer = zip_file.get_input_stream('footer.png')
  end

  @theme.save
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I don't receive any error or failure, but the Theme is saved with empty values for the resources and the files are not created in my upload folder.

I believe I can get this working by extracting the zip to temporary files and then reading those files into the CarrierWave properties, but this seems like a very round the bush way of solving the problem.

How can I upload and extract a zip in memory and assign its contents to my CarrierWave enhanced models?